# Can't hide line on top of tablayout

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.5

I want to show Tablayout with shadow in the bottom. 
So I try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/appbar" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/balanceTitleContainer"
            style="@style/ImpressiveCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_gap"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_gap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/baseTokenContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/baseTokenTokenView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_gap"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/topUpButton"
                        style="@style/PrimaryButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:text="@string/topUp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton.Overlay" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                        style="@style/PrimaryButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:text="@string/send"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton.Overlay" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="@dimen/line_divider_shadow_height"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/my_vauchers" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

the appbar layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    style="@style/AppbarTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I use

```
android:background="@color/white"
               android:elevation="@dimen/line_divider_shadow_height"
```

to show shadow.

here result:

[image]

As you can see in Tablayout also show gray line on the top (above **My Vaucher**). But I need gray line (shadow) only on the bottom of Tablayout.

Comment: A simple workaround could be using a gradient shadow drawable and placing it below the TabLayout and hiding the default shadows

Comment: @SaurabhBadola Is it possible without workaround?

Comment: You probably need this workaround to achieve what you want. There is no issue in that.